# Why the need of eval() in this code snippet?

Tags: python, json, eval

I am currently working on a small project in python using an API layer called "pybtsync" that provides an direct python access for BTSync. I tried to familiarize myself with it by looking at its source code where I found this:

```
def _request_function(self, method_name, arguments='', key=None):
    URL = 'http://' + self._address + ':' + self._port +'/api?method=' + method_name + '&' + arguments
    request = requests.get(URL, auth=(self._login, self._password))
    request_data = eval(request.text)
    if key is not None:
        return request_data[key]
    return request_data
```

I know that the API from BTsync returns in json formatting. So why isn't a json.load(request.text) not sufficient? I see a potential security issue with using eval() here. Is there any reason I do not see?

The whole code from pybtsync can be found here:
https://github.com/tiagomacarios/pybtsync/blob/master/pybtsync/pybtsync.py#L239

For more context about the BTSync api:
http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/developers/api

Comment: There **is** a security issue using `eval()` there, and `json.loads()` should have been sufficient. Heck, `requests.json()` would have been enough.

Comment: Not just a security issue, valid JSON is not necessarily valid Python.   JSON has the literals `true`, `false`, and `null` which become `True`, `False`, and `None` in Python when decoded correctly, but will result in a SyntaxError when passed into `eval()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That just confirmed what I thought. Will fix it and put a commit to the author of the pybtsync hopefully he will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a security issue; if I can alter the DNS server your code uses or use a man-in-the-middle server then I can send you arbitrary Python code.

And if the API was ever updated to include JSON `null` or boolean values, the `eval()` call would fail for regular JSON responses as well.

The code should call `request.json()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

eval in interpreted language means invoke interpreter itself on target text, in other words, trying to parse and execute the text as a program.

In your case the result is json formated "string", not a json object, invoking eval on it will parse the string thus giving you an object, additionally, json.load will return unicode strings, while eval wont

Comment: so, if I understand it correctly, eval() is needed here to make said json string into an python object. Would there be a better way, instead of using eval()?

Comment: I've checked it and there is NO need for using eval(). requests.json() is enough and does the same thing.